# How to describe this object using an interface?

Tags: typescript

I have an object that looks like this:

```
var MyObject = {
    property1: {
        name: "name1",
        args: [1, 2, 3, 4],
    },

    property2: {
        name: "name2",
        args: [1, 1],
    },
    ...
}
```

`MyObject` contains many properties, each of them is an object that has a string and an array of numbers.

Is it possible to create an interface that describe the type of MyObject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to define `MyObject` as an object that holds an arbitrary number of properties all of the same type then you can use the [`Dictionary` array type definition (TypeScript documentation)](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#interfaces-array-types).

Here is a [Typescript playground example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=%2F**%0D%0A%20*%20Define%20a%20dictionary%20interface.%0D%0A%20*%20%0D%0A%20*%20Arbitrary%20properties%20may%20be%20added%20as%20long%20as%0D%0A%20*%20they%20satisfy%20the%20%60IMyProperty%60%20interface.%0D%0A%20*%2F%0D%0Ainterface%20IMyObjectDictionary%20%7B%0D%0A%09%5Bproperty%3A%20string%5D%3A%20IMyProperty%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20IMyProperty%20%7B%0D%0A%09name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%09args%3A%20number%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Define%20%60obj1%60%20to%20be%20an%20%60IMyObjectDictionary%60.%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%0D%0A%2F%2F%20All%20properties%20must%20be%20%60IMyProperty%60%20instances.%0D%0Avar%20obj1%3A%20IMyObjectDictionary%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%09property1%3A%20%7Bname%3A%20''%2C%20args%3A%20%5B%5D%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09%2F%2F%20You%20define%20as%20many%20%60IMyProperty%60%20properties%0D%0A%09%2F%2F%20as%20needed.%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09%2F%2F%20But%20all%20properties%20*must*%20match%20the%20%60IMyProperty%60%20interface.%0D%0A%09%2F%2F%2Cproperty2%3A%20number%09%2F%2F%20%3C--%20This%20would%20give%20a%20compiler%20error%20because%20it's%20not%20an%20%60IMyProperty%60.%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Must%20access%20properties%20using%20array%20notation.%0D%0Avar%20b%20%3D%20obj1%5B'property1'%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20TypeScript%20knows%20that%20%60b%60%20is%20an%20%60IMyProperty%60.%0D%0Ab.name%3B%09%2F%2F%20Valid%0D%0Ab.args%3B%20%2F%2F%20Valid%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20b.temp%3B%09%2F%2F%20%3C--%20Invalid%20-%20%60temp%60%20does%20not%20exist%20on%20%60IMyProperty%60.%0D%0A%2F%2F%20b%20%3D%201%3B%20%2F%2F%20%3C--%20This%20would%20give%20a%20compiler%20error.%20'number'%20is%20not%20an%20%60IMyProperty%60.) of the dictionary interface:

```
/**
 * Define a dictionary interface.
 */
interface IMyObjectDictionary {
    [property: string]: IMyProperty;
}


interface IMyProperty {
    name: string;
    args: number[];
}


// Define `obj1` to be an `IMyObjectDictionary`.
// 
// All properties must be `IMyProperty` instances.
var obj1: IMyObjectDictionary = {
    property1: {name: '', args: []}

    // You define as many `IMyProperty` properties
    // as needed.

    // But all properties *must* match the `IMyProperty` interface.
    //,property2: number    // <-- This would give a compiler error because it's not an `IMyProperty`.
};

// Must access properties using array notation.
var b = obj1['property1'];

// TypeScript knows that `b` is an `IMyProperty`.
b.name; // Valid
b.args; // Valid

// b.temp;  // <-- Invalid - `temp` does not exist on `IMyProperty`.
// b = 1; // <-- This would give a compiler error. 'number' is not an `IMyProperty`.
```

If you need properties of mixed types then you will need to use a regular interface definition.

e.g.

```
interface IMyObjectDictionary {
    property1: IMyProperty;
    property2: IMyProperty;
    // ...

    // Allows properties that aren't `IMyProperty`
    // but you have to define all properties.
    index: number;
}
```

Comment: It is a very big drawback that typescript forces you to use array notation, i.e.  `obj['property1']`, when it could let you use the standard `obj.property1` notation. Is there any alternative / workaround for that?

Comment: @LuisCrespo to use dot notation you can use a standard interface definition (like I show at the bottom of my answer) but you will have to list all members so TypeScript knows about them. You can add named properties to a dictionary interface as long as the properties are all of the same type.

Comment: @Sly_cardinal The dictionary interface is great when you don't know which properties are there going to be in your objects, but you do know that they all must be of the same type. The standard interface definition forces you to define those properties in advance.